# CPU Overusage Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, cpu, fan, temperature

I'm very new to Linux and Ubuntu. I did install Ubuntu 14.04 on my Vaio laptop and all was working fine. Yesterday, I did the last update and since then my fan is working all the time. CPU temperature is around 75-80 degrees celcius. I also saw that some processes use a lot of my CPU:

[CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dapWS.png)

What can I do to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Which graphics driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel team wiki contains a page that helps diagnose power consumption issues: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/IdentifyingIssues

In your example, init is really way too busy for some reason, which looks just plain wrong. If this persists and does not change, then one should file a bug, as init should be using only a small slice of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem. Yesterday I disabled ipv6 following instructions on a post and they were doing it by modifying the init file. It seems it was not a good idea. I put back the init file as it was and everything is working normally.